# python - bind property attribute of one instance to another class

Tags: python, class, dynamic, properties, descriptor

I'd like to bind a specific property/descriptor on an instance of one class to an another attribute on an instance of another class (dynamic property?). Something like:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value


class Child(Base):
    pass

class Parent(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Parent, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.children = []

    def add_attrs(self, attr_child):
        for attr, child in attr_child:
            self.children.append(child)
            setattr(self, attr, child.value)

av = [("id_", Child(123)), ("name", Child("test"))]

p = Parent()
p.add_attrs(av)

assert p.name == p.children[-1].value

# at this point p.name == "test"
p.name = "abc"

# would like above to also set the child.value to "abc" 
assert p.name == p.children[-1].value
```

Ultimately I could do `p.name.value` if instead I set name to the Child instance, but I was wondering if this could be done as I think it's a bit nicer. I tried something like:

```
def get_dict_attr(obj, attr):
    for obj in [obj] + obj.__class__.mro():
        if attr in obj.__dict__:
            return obj.__dict__[attr]
    raise AttributeError


class Parent(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Parent, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.children = []

    def add_attrs(self, attr_child):
        for attr, child in attr_child:
            self.children.append(child)
            val = get_dict_attr(child, "value")
            setattr(self, attr, val)
```

but then `p.name` == `<property object at ... >`. Wondering if something like this is possible and haven't come across anything suggesting it is so far. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible? Possibly, using a custom [data descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) (rather than property). I think it would be really hacky and the amount of time you'd save rather than just creating a new property for the new class would be minimal. Should you do it? absolutely not! The code above is hard enough to follow anyway ;)